# Why should the speed of all the fluid particles passing through a given point be same in a steady flow of?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, flow

This is a general condition (or say the definition) for steady flow of fluids that ***the speed of each molecules on passing through a given point on their path (the streamline curve) should be the same.***

**But i really don't understand how does the equality of speed at a given point for all particles ensure a streamline flow?**

## or

**Why can't a particle have a different speed when it reaches a given point from where another particle has passed earlier with some speed in a steady flow?**

## Or

***How does different speed at a given point makes the flow turbulent  ?***

Comment: Note that the condition is about *particles*, not molecules. These "particles" are abstract mathematical entities: the fluid is represented by a continuum, and the "particles" are the points of this continuum (they can be taken as points of a differential manifold). You can also call them "volume elements". The motion of such a particle can be put into correspondence with a spatially and temporally averaged motion (over some prescribed space and time intervals) of the real molecules constituting the fluid.

Comment: What's unclear with the question ? Voters for closing the question may share their doubts with the question..

Answer (score 2):

In fluid dynamics, if the velocity of a fluid is constant in time (over a particular region of space and during a particular interval of time):
$$\frac{\partial \pmb{v}(\pmb{x},t)}{\partial t} = 0 \quad \forall \pmb{x}\ ,$$
or in other words, if the velocity of the fluid depends only on the position, then the fluid is said to have a *steady flow* (in that region and during that time interval). The word "steady" seems quite an appropriate term to describe such a situation.

This is just a *definition*, a matter of terminology. There are no requirements.

Other quantities, such as temperature, or pressure, are also called *steady* if their time derivative vanishes everywhere.

A mathematical and physical *consequence* of steady flow, that is, of the fact that the time derivative of the velocity is zero everywhere, is this:

Suppose that an element of fluid which is at position $\pmb{x}$ at some time $t_1$, is then found at position $\pmb{x}'$ after a time interval $\Delta t$, that is, at time $t_1+\Delta t$. Then another element of fluid which is at position $\pmb{x}$ at some other time $t_2$ must also be found at position $\pmb{x}'$ after a time interval $\Delta t$, that is, at time $t_2 + \Delta t$.

The reason can be intuitively understood by considering a very short time interval $\Delta t$. The position of the first fluid element at $t_1+\Delta t$ is given by
$$\pmb{x} + \pmb{v}(\pmb{x},t_1)\ \Delta t \ ;$$
and the position of the second fluid element at $t_2+\Delta t$ is given by
$$\pmb{x} + \pmb{v}(\pmb{x}, t_2)\ \Delta t \ .$$
But these two new positions must be the same, because $\pmb{v}(\pmb{x}, t_1) = \pmb{v}(\pmb{x}, t_2)$, since $\pmb{v}$ doesn't depend on time.

It can of course happen that the fluid element that is at $\pmb{x}$ at time $t_1$ has some velocity, and another fluid element that is at the same position $\pmb{x}$ at a later time $t_2$ will have a different velocity. Then, *by definition*, the flow is *not* steady in this case.

It must be stressed that the discussion above concerns *fluid elements*, often called "particles" in fluid dynamics, but not real molecules. In fluid dynamics, which is a branch of continuum thermomechanics, matter is mathematically modelled as an infinitely divisible continuum. The term "particle" denotes a *point* of this idealized continuum, not a real molecule.

In connecting fluid mechanics with molecular dynamics, a fluid element can be thought of as an instantaneous collection of (real) molecules in a small region of time. The velocity of that element is the mass-weighted average of the velocities of those molecules. In general the molecules that belong to a fluid element change with time. See the references below for a more detailed and mathematical discussion about this.

This means that in steady flow the real molecules do not need to have exactly the same velocities in passing through some point $\pmb{x}$ – in fact, it may be that no molecule at all passes through that point. What happens in steady flow is that at each time $t$ the *weighted average* of the velocities of molecules found *in a small region around $\pmb{x}$* at time $t$ always has the same approximate (within macroscopic-measurement precision) value. ("And how small should the region be?" – check the discussion in the last reference below.)

#### References

For the definition of steady flow and other kinematical situations check §67 of

- Truesdell, Toupin: [*The Classical Field Theories*](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-642-45943-6_2).

I consider this text the ultimate reference for this kind of definitions, their mathematical and physical consequences, and also their history.

For the relation between the idealized mathematical objects of continuum thermomechanics and those of molecular dynamics, check for example

- Murdoch: [*On the identification of continuum concepts and fields with molecular variables*](https://doi.org/10.1007/s00161-010-0146-9)

and the references given there.

Comment: thanks for ur answer .... One thing I wanna confirm.. in one of your paragraphs for giving physical intuition you mentioned that the positions occupied by a fluid element after passing through a point in a small time interval is the same for another fluid element passing though the same point latter in time.. .. **So is this equivalence in distance traveled a way to prevent density change?** What are the effects that this property can have on the properties of fluid ?

Comment: you mentioned that one of yeh consequence of steady flow is this : **Suppose that an element of fluid which is at position xx at some time t1, is then found at position xx′ after a time interval Δt, that is, at time t1+Δt. Then another element of fluid which is at position xx at some other time t2 must also be found at position xx′ after a time interval Δt, that is, at time t2+Δt**.. I just wanna know ***what does this equivalence physically indicates ?*** Does it show that the fluid in study is incompressible ?

Comment: @Ankit You can calculate or check any effects you want mathematically. Incompressibility corresponds to the condition $\nabla\cdot\pmb{v}=0$. This condition is independent from $\partial\pmb{v}/\partial t = 0$, so a steady flow *can* have density changes.

Comment: @Ankit I don't quite understand your second comment. The equality is a physical equality. If the steady flow is that of a river, and you place a leaf at some point, it will be transported to some point – say, near a surfacing rock nearby. If you wait a while, and then place another leaf on the same spot, it will also be transported near the surfacing rock. This is a physical phenomenon or condition.

Answer (score 1):

A [steady flow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluid_dynamics#Steady_versus_unsteady_flow) is that in which flow properties at a given point are not a function of time:
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\big(\cdot\big) = 0$$

Therefore, flow velocity (as well as pressure, density etc...) remains fixed at any given point in the flow domain, and different particles arriving at said point at different times cannot have different velocities.

Comment: thanks for ur answer too ... But I think I need to know the exact reason how the flow velocity matters ? .. may be you could edit ur answr and include the reason but nonetheless no worries if u can't.. thanks